# UTF-8 unicode encoding in terminal

Tags: bash, unicode, utf-8, terminal

NOTE: I have looked through related threads but can't find the solution to my problem. 
Hello. I am creating a small game where you can play a round of poker in the terminal. For this I of course want the spades, hearts, clover and diamonds symbols. Using \u2660 etc I get the icons to display in my IDE, but they wont display in my terminal. I have tried the following:

```
locale
```

displays

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I have

```
# coding=UTF-8
```

in the program.
I also have

```
LANG=en_EN.UTF8
```

in my bash_profile.

I am using a Mac if that's relevant.
[image: Terminal options]

This is from the terminal settings.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Add your code to your question.

Comment: At least on my Linux system `UTF-8` is not a valid locale, but `C.UTF-8` is.
You can list all allowed locales with `locale -a`.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal needs to support Unicode (this is pretty standard these days), your locale needs to be something ending with “.UTF-8” ([“UTF-8” is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53457057/utf-8-unicode-encoding-in-terminal#comment93786300_53457057)) and your font needs to include the relevant glyph. For example, in my urxvt with `LC_CTYPE="en_NZ.utf8"` and the DejaVu Sans Mono the [suit characters](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/suits-of-the-cards/) show up as expected:

[image: suit characters]